# Collapsible List in KendoUi

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am very new to KendoUI and want to implement a Collapsible list that was built using JQMobile . I have searched through the net but didn't find any thing like collapsible list KendoUI . Is there any equivalent of Collapsible list in JQMobile to KendoUI.Also can anyone suggest some good tutorials to get started with except the official ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo Mobile doesn't have an equivalent widget, but collapsible panels are really easy to implement yourself with a few lines of Javascript, or you could use the [Kendo Web PanelBar](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/panelbar/index) widget. It just won't have mobile "native looking" styling by default, but you could put the Kendo Mobile ListView widget inside a Kendo Web PanelBar, then you would only have to fix the styling of the PanelBar's header element.

Comment: Thank you. I also came to know the same .If Panels are to be used for collapsible then what is the Jquery equivalent of the panels?